# Search by tag [x] OR [Y]

Tags: support, tags, tag-search

Is there a way to find results that match either one tag or another (with or without a keyword included?)

For example searching  `[x] [y]` will return content with both `[x]` and `[y]` - can I preform a search to find content with tags `[x]` or `[y]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[x] OR [Y]
```

It's a simple as that. You can put all the tags you want to follow in that search and you will even get a live refresh on all on them in one browser tab.

Comment: i swear i tried that and it didn't (seem to) work.  maybe one of the tags i used was too dominant.  Anyway, thanks!